# TCP Message framing + recv() [linux]: Good conventions?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, message, recv

I am trying to create a p2p applications on Linux, which I want to run as efficiently as possible.

The issue I have is with managing packets. As we know, there may be more than one packet in the recv() buffer at any time, so there is a need to have some kind of message framing system to make sure that multiple packets are not treated as one big packet.

So at the moment my packet structure is:

```
(u16int Packet Length):(Packet Data)
```

Which requires two calls to recv(); one to get the packet size, and one to get the packet.

There are two main problems with this:

```
1. A malicious peer could send a packet with a size header of 
  something large, but not send any more data. The application will 
  hang on the second recv(), waiting for data that will never come.
2. Assuming that calling Recv() has a noticeable performance penalty
  (I actually have no idea, correct me if I am wrong) calling Recv() twice 
  will slow the program down.
```

What is the best way to structure packets/Recieving system for both the best efficiency and stability? How do other applications do it? What do you recommend?

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your "framing" of messages within a TCP stream is right on.

You could consider putting a "magic cookie" in front of each frame (e.g. write the 32-bit int "0xdeadbeef" at the top of each frame header in addition to the packet length) such that it becomes obvious that your are reading a frame header on the first of each recv() pairs.  It the magic integer isn't present at the start of the message, you have gotten out of sync and need to tear the connection down.

Multiple recv() calls will not likely be a performance hit.  As a matter of fact, because TCP messages can get segmented, coalesced, and stalled in unpredictable ways, you'll likely need to call recv() in a loop until you get all the data you expected. This includes your two byte header as well as for the larger read of the payload bytes. It's entirely possible you call "recv" with a 2 byte buffer to read the "size" of the message, but only get 1 byte back. (Call recv again, and you'll get the subsequent bytes).  What I tell the developers on my team - code your network parsers as if it was possible that recv only delivered 1 byte at a time.

You can use non-blocking sockets and the "select" call to avoid hanging. If the data doesn't arrive within a reasonable amount of time (or more data arrives than expected - such that syncing on the next message becomes impossible), you just tear the connection down.

I'm working on a P2P project of my own. Would love to trade notes. Follow up with me offline if you like.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the others, TCP is a reliable protocol, so a packet magic header is useless unless you fear that your client code isn't stable or that unsolicited clients connect to your port number.

Create a buffer for each client and use non-blocking sockets and `select`/`poll`/`epoll`/`kqueue`. If there is data available from a client, read as much as you can, it doesn't matter if you read more "packets". Then check whether you've read enough so the size field is available, if so, check that you've read the whole packet (or more). If so, process the packet. Then if there's more data, you can repeat this procedure. If there is partial packet left, you can move that to the start of your buffer, or use a circular buffer so you don't have to do those memmove-s.

Client timeout can be handled in your `select`/... loop.

That's what I would use if you're doing something complex with the received packet data. If all you do is to write the results to a file (in bigger chunks) then `sendfile`/`splice` yields better peformance. Just read packet length (could be multiple reads) then use multiple calls to sendfile until you've read the whole packet (keep track of how much left to read).

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-blocking calls to `recv()` (by setting SOCK_NONBLOCK on the socket), and wait for them to become ready for reading data using `select()` (with a timeout) in a loop.

Then if a file descriptor is in the "waiting for data" state for too long, you can just close the socket.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a stream-oriented protocol - it doesn't actually have any concept of packets.  So, in addition to recieving multiple application-layer packets in one `recv()` call, you might also recieve only *part* of an application-layer packet, with the remainder coming in a future `recv()` call.

This implies that robust reciever behaviour is obtained by receiving as much data as possible at each `recv()` call, then buffering that data in an application-layer buffer until you have at least one full application-layer packet.  This also avoids your two-calls-to-`recv()` problem.

To always recieve as much data as possible at each `recv()`, without blocking, you should use non-blocking sockets and call `recv()` until it returns -1 with `errno` set to `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, a leading magic number (OT: *man file*) is a good (99.999999%) solution to identify datagram boundaries, and timeout (using non-blocking recv()) is good for detecting missing/late packet.

If you count on attackers, you should put a **CRC** in your packet. If a professional attacker really wants, he/she will figure out - sooner or later - how your CRC works, but it's even harder than create a packet without CRC. (Also, if safety is critical, you will find SSL libs/examples/code on the Net.)